# Finding energy of a rubber band

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, potential-energy

I'm solving a thermodynamics exercise and at one point I'm asked to find the energy if a rubber band. The rubber band has temperaturte $T$ lenght $L$ and tension $J$. I'm given the following quantities:
$$
(\frac{\partial J}{\partial T})_L=a(\frac{L}{L_0})(1-\epsilon(\frac{L}{L_0})^{-3})\\
(\frac{\partial J}{\partial L})_T=aT(\frac{L}{L_0})(1+2\epsilon(\frac{L}{L_0})^{-3})
$$
where $a$ and $\epsilon$ are just two costants. I was able to find that
$$
J(T,L)=aT(\frac{L}{L_0})(1+2\epsilon(\frac{L}{L_0})^{-3})+k
$$
Where $k$ is a constant independent of $T$ and $L$.
I'm stuck at the point where I'm asked to find the most general form of the energy E(T,L), compatible with the first principle of thermodynamics. The way I procedeed is to express:
$$
dS(L,T)=\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT+\frac{\partial S}{\partial L}dL\\
dS(L,T)=\frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}dT+( \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial E}{\partial L}-J)dL
$$
This, using Maxwell's relations
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial L \partial T}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial T \partial T}
$$
This leads me to
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial L}=T\frac{\partial J}{\partial L}-J=cost
$$
But this seems absurd to me. You get something like
$$
E(T,L)= cost*L+f(T)
$$
But this just seems absurd to me because how can the energy be linear in L?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the energy growing as a linear function of the separation *is* characteristic of rubber bands (and other, more exotic systems, like strings or flux tubes between quarks).

One way to understand this is to compute the electrostatic potential for a point charge in one spatial dimension. You will find that the potential grows linearly with distance from the point charge (this is essentially the integral of the result that the electric field for an infinitely large, charged sheet is constant). An elastic medium obeys the Poisson equation, and a rubber band is essentially a 1-dimensional elastic medium.

More physically, the linear potential means that the rubber band wants to shrink. It costs energy to increase the length of the rubber band. This fits very well with your intuition of stretched rubber bands.

Of course this is a simplified model, and the linear potential is an approximation that breaks down in at least two ways for a real rubber band. First, the rubber band has some equilibrium shape. If you decrease the length to the point where the rubber band has no tension, then it has no tendency to change its length. Second, the rubber band has a breaking point where the internal tension becomes too large and the band breaks. So in reality, there is some range of lengths where the linear potential is a good approximation, but this breaks down if the length of the rubber band is too small or too large.